# Restore form with combobox after navigating back

Tags: firefox, combobox, jquery-chosen

when using a form with a combobox Firefox does not restore the form data after this element.

I used first the jquery-chosen plugin and also tried the jquery-combobox (from autocomplete). Both have the same problem for me in Firefox. Internet Explorer and Chrome does not have this issue. I tried Firefox version 17 (ESR) and 22.

The **HTML** code looks like this:

```
<div>
    <form action="submit.html">
        <input type="text" />
        <div>
            <select data-placeholder="Choose a Country..." id="chosen">
                <option value=""></option>
                <option value="United States">United States</option>
                <option value="United Kingdom">United Kingdom</option>
                <option value="Afghanistan">Afghanistan</option>
            </select>
        </div>
        <input type="text" />
        <br/>
        <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
    </form>
</div>
```

And I initialize the combobox with:

```
$(function () {
    $("#chosen").chosen();
});
```

Here is a Fiddle which shows the problem: http://jsfiddle.net/Ne5v7/2/
Please open the URL with Firefox. Fill the form, press submit (you see 404) and now navigating back to the form. The input field after the combobox will not be restored.

Any suggestion for this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like this was a known bug in Firefox and will be solved in Firefox 26, which will be released at December 2013.

https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=910652